# Adding RelativeLayout above a ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I'm trying to add a RelativeLayout, that contains 2 TextViews, above a ListView as a header, but am having trouble.  The code I have so far shows the ListView, the footer, but no header:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         >

    <!-- Header -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        >
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/headerIcon" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         />          
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/headerText" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="#919191"
          />
          </RelativeLayout>
    <!-- Header -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="0dp"       
        >           
             <ListView 
                android:id="@android:id/list"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            />

             <TextView android:id="@android:id/empty"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="No items"
                android:padding="5dp"
                />
     </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Footer -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        >
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/footerIcon" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         /> 
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/footerText" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="right"
         /> 
    </RelativeLayout>        
    <!-- Footer -->
  </RelativeLayout>
```

**UPDATE:**

I have it partially working.  The following code does show the header TextViews, but when I scroll the ListView, the header layout flickers and disappears.  Why is working with layouts in Android so frustrating?

This is the code that partically works:

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        >  

     <RelativeLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            >

            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/headerIcon" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:background="#919191"
             />

            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/headerText" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:background="#919191"
              />
    </RelativeLayout>   

     <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
      >        
       <ListView android:id="@android:id/list" android:layout_width="fill_parent"  android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

        <TextView android:id="@android:id/empty"
            style="@style/BaseStyle"
            android:text="No keywords entered"
            android:padding="5dp"
         />
    </LinearLayout>

     <RelativeLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            >
            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/statusUpdated" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                style="@style/Status"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:background="#919191"
             />

            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/statusItems" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                style="@style/Status"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:background="#919191"
              />
    </RelativeLayout>   

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!-- Header -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/llayout"
        >
  <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/llayout">
         <ListView />
         <TextView />
  </LinearLayout >

 <!-- Footer-->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below=="@+id/llayout"
        / >
```

Answer (score 0):

Your LinearLayout is set to fill_parent and may cause your problem